# how to itereate an json object in angularjs using for loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have one array i want  to iterate that in the iteration process we check one condition if condition is true we return one  value otherwise we return else part I write some code but its not working.
                 the loop will not terminated if condition is true how can i do that cam anyone help me?

```
 $scope.bgImages = []; //it having some objects
 $scope.job = []; //it also having some objeccts
 //if both elements are matching we return one value
 $scope.getJobDepartmentImg = function() {
     var jobDepartment = $scope.job.department;
     for (var i in $scope.bgImages) {
         var department = $scope.bgImages[i].departmentName;
         var job_header = $scope.bgImages[i].s3ImageUrl;
         if (jobDepartment === department) {
             return job_header;
         } else {
             return default_job_header;
         }
     }
 };
```

The loop is not terminated if condition is satisfiedd that method will continiouslyy can anyone help me?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#break_statement

Answer (score 0):

put an second return outside else statement

```
$scope.getJobDepartmentImg = function() {
        var jobDepartment = $scope.job.department;
        for (var i in $scope.bgImages) {
            var department = $scope.bgImages[i].departmentName;
            var job_header = $scope.bgImages[i].s3ImageUrl;
            if(jobDepartment === department){
                return job_header;
            }
        }
        return default_job_header;
}
```

it will iterate through array and return job_header if it finds one, or return default if loop ends